# How to change name of attaching SQL database in pyodbc - Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to attach a database through python pyodbc and then save to dataframe. I found and a solution here [How to open a SQL Server .mdf file with Python (pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307559/how-to-open-a-sql-server-mdf-file-with-python-pandas)

But how can I change the name of the attaching database? So when I am attaching the database based on the code

```py
r'AttachDbFileName=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\zzz.mdf;'
```

am I also able to set the name of the database?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You cannot attach a SQL Server data file. You have to connect to a SQL Server instance (and a database in it) using pyodbc and a odbc driver for SQL Server.

Comment: Have you tried just specifying the database name as `DATABASE=somename;` in the connection string?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gord Thompson.